# Multiple logical expressions in one if statement in java

Tags: java, boolean, short-circuiting

Hi I have this example:

```
  (1)
  if(false && false ||true){
            System.out.println("a");
  }
```

**result:**

```
a
```

and

```
  (2)
  if(false && false | true){
            System.out.println("a");
  }
```

**result:**

```
(empty)
```

In case (1) we have short-circuit OR , but in the second we have long-circuit OR. From where comes the difference in the behavior? I know that the expression is evaluated from left to right and AND have bigger priority than OR, so I can't figure out why this happens in case 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)

```
if (false && false || true) {
    System.out.println("a");
}
```

Here `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

1. `false && false` gets evaluated first resulting `false`.
2. `false || true` gets evaluated resulting `true`.

So the result outputs "a".

(2)

```
if (false && false | true) {
    System.out.println("a");
}
```

Here `|` has higher precedence than `&&`

1. `false | true` gets evaluated first resulting `true`.
2. `false && true` gets evaluated resulting `false`.

So nothing is output.

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 5):

`&&` has priority over `||` but not over `|`. See [operator precedence list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: SO first will be calculated false | true -> true ,and then false && true->false?